# How do I compare times to today's date?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm trying to compare `datetime`s to `time`s in Yii2 while using today's date as a base. I've got to this line, but I'm pretty sure it isn't the proper way to do this (and is not working):

```php
$items = mtype::find()->select(["id"])->where(["<","last_run","from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(curdate())+unix_timestamp(concat('1970-01-01 ',time_format(curtime(),'%H:%i:00'))))"])->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: Are you storing "last_run" in timestemp ??

Comment: $items = mtype::find()->select(["id"])->where(["<","last_run",time()])->asArray()->all();

Comment: @YasinPatel: last_run is `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to select the lines where the time of day of `last_run` is earlier than the current time.

If so you can do the following:

```
SELECT id
FROM xxx
WHERE TIME(last_run) < CURTIME();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html tells you anything you need to know about date / time functions ;)